# php5:pass objects through Form ? can it be done?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, http-post

i have this littel problem with a test app.

Current look:

```
<form>
<span>1:Question goes here </span>
<input type=hidden name=true_1 value=10>
<input type=hidden name=false_1 value=20>
<input type=hidden name=target_1 value=color>
<select name=answer_1[]><option>blah</option><option>etc</option></select>

<span>2:Question goes here </span>
<input type=hidden name=true_2 value=40>
<input type=hidden name=false_2 value=20>
<input type=hidden name=target_2 value=size>
<select name=answer_2[]><option>blah</option><option>etc</option></select>
</form>
```

currently i use a script that explode("_",$get); so i can handle each question with its own properties.

**Current approach**
1.Get questions from database. (question,target,true,false,answers)
2.loop throught them and creat a form similar to one i wrote above for all questions
3.When posted i explode to get each question properties alone
4.pass them to function that evaluate if answer correct or false and give score

**what im trying to do is to turn this into oop**

1.creating an object for each question and assign its own properties(question,true,false,target,answer) foreach($question)$q[1]=new question();

2.echo the $q[] for user to answer.

3.receive the $q[] after user answer and $_POST them.

hope i described this right.but its very important for me to keep every thing dynamically so i need to include hidden fields.
is it doable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use json datatype for this kind of task (assuming your objects just store data, not methods nor require __sleep, __wakeup, etc).

```
<input name="fooBar" value="<?php echo json_encode(/*some_array_with_data*/);?>">
```

After form POST you can do something like

```
$_POST['fooBar'] = json_decode($_POST['fooBar']);
```

and start iterating resulting array.

NB. since json_encode results in string containing chars like **"** you should also use base64_encode, url_encode or something like that.